# WIFI: iPhone/iPad getting much slower bandwidth than laptop

Tags: wireless-networking, router, iphone, bandwidth, cable-modem

I just got cable internet installed (Comcast). It claims that my down speed should be 25mbit. Over wifi, I get close to that on my laptop, but only about 8 on average with my iPhone/iPad.

I'm using [testmy.net](http://testmy.net/) in the browser on all devices. I have an [ARRIS / Motorola SurfBoard SB6141 DOCSIS 3.0 Cable Modem](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AJHDZSI) and a [Medialink Wireless N Broadband Router](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00A3YN0Z0). iPhone 5 and iPad 2.

I read somewhere that disabling [WMM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Multimedia_Extensions) and the firewall on the router would help (*is this even a safe idea?*). I've tried both, and neither seem to make much of a difference, if any at all (sidebar: I've noticed that my download speeds vary wildly with cable internet... on my laptop, I'll get 12 down, then 22 five minutes later. Is this typical for cable internet?).

Comment: Which iPhone / iPad do you have?

Comment: Also, have you seen this thread? https://discussions.apple.com/message/15065064#15065064

Comment: And there's no inherent danger in turning off WMM or QoS as described in the Apple discussion.  However it may affect other devices on your network such as streaming boxes etc.

Comment: @sgtbeano Question edited with iPhone 5 and iPad 2... thanks for pointing out that omission.

Comment: Lots of people on the apple discussion mentioning the iPad 2 - I'm almost all the way through it now but turning off WMM and QoS seems to be helping a lot, as well as turning off multiple mode too i.e. n rather than a/b/g/n etc.  This page https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2398063?start=150&tstart=0 has a good post on checking channel space on your wireless too.

Comment: If any of this helps, I'll write up some sort of answer.....

Comment: @sgtbeano Yes! A write up would be a tremendous help. Thanks. Regarding your suggestion to disable multi mode: my router can do b/g, b, g, or b/g/n... so I can't only run in n mode. Bummer.

Comment: @sgtbeano Oh... and what about disabling the firewall? Helpful in any way? Is that a really dangerous thing to do?

Comment: @sgtbeano Turning off WMM (QoS) usually disables all the 802.11n rates, as the 802.11n standard requires QoS.

Comment: @Spiff "disables all the 802.11n rates"... is that a good thing or a bad thing? What does that mean?

Comment: @Sam It's a bad thing. 802.11n (which some vendors call "Wireless-N") is what enables PHY data rates above the 54mbps upper limit of the previous technology (802.11g topped out at 54mbps). Turning off 802.11n rates turns your 300mbps 2007-era Wi-Fi router into a 54mbps 2003-era 802.11g ("Wireless-G") router.

Comment: @Sam do **not** turn off your firewall, that would be bad.

Answer (score -1):

It's the Comcast router, don't change your Apple settings!  Turn off your personal router.  Using a pen, press the reset button on the top of the back of your Comcast box and hold for a FULL 30 slow count seconds.  Let go and allow the router to reboot, say at least 5 minutes.  Go watch TV for a while, don't rush this step!  Come back and turn on your personal router.  All fixed!